# python pandas read_excel error "Value must be either numerical or a string containing a wild card"

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I dont know why this error occurs.

```
pd.read_excel('data/A.xlsx', usecols=["B", "C"])
```

Then I get this error:

```
"Value must be either numerical or a string containing a wild card"
```

So i change my code use nrows all data

```
pd.read_excel('data/A.xlsx', usecols=["B","C"], nrows=172033)
```

Then there is no error and a dataframe is created.

my excel file has 172034 rows, 1st is column name.

Comment: It doesn't look like you pass a list of columns, but a single string of comma separated values.
Try `usecols="B,C"`
I think the method can take a true list of strings, but that might be only when there are named columns.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Is it possible to add the image of sample of excel you are trying to read?

Answer (score 21):

If you deselect all your filters the read_excel function should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 21):

This problem is unique to the latest version of the Openpyxl library, **v3.1.2**.
Downgrading to **v.3.0.10** will fix this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: omg, you saved me. Thank you

Comment: For those who want to know if this is fixed, you can have a look at the status of the issue at https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1967

Comment: pip install 'openpyxl==3.0.10'

Comment: When I do this, I get errors from pandas not supporting the older version, and trying to downgrade pandas gives me even more errors

Answer (score 1):

It is mainly because you have applied some filters to the excel file and saved it. So while reading the file pandas not able to recognize those columns. So please remove the filter and read the file again it will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35632015)